# JSON always returning "client_id not specified"

Tags: javascript, json, arcgis

I'm trying to get a token from the ArcGIS Online service using a Javascript. However, it's always returning an error which indicates the client_id isn't specified.

Am I doing everything right here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyJSONText = '{"client_id":"<<MY_CLIENT_ID>>","client_secret":"<<MY_CLIENT_SECRET>>","grant_type":"client_credentials","expiration":"1440","f":"json"}';
    var MyJSON = JSON.parse(MyJSONText);
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token/");
    xhr.send(MyJSON);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Edit - full error is:

```
{"error":{"code":400,"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"client_id not specified","message":"client_id not specified","details":[]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve an access token using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request:

```
POST https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: www.arcgis.com
Content-Length: 126

client_id=<YOUR ID>&client_secret=<YOUR SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials&expiration=1440&f=json
```

which means that you might need to specify the Content-Type request header when making the XHR request:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

and of course properly formatting the body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON. In my tests this endpoint didn't work with JSON payload.

Unfortunately from what it looks, the token endpoint doesn't support setting the `Content-Type` request header in its CORS policy which means that you might be out of luck in calling it with javascript. Besides [`their documentation`](https://developers.arcgis.com/authentication/accessing-arcgis-online-services/#getting-a-token) doesn't mention anything about `javascript` as a supported language.

So basically if you want to make this work you could get the access token on your server side and pass it along to the client.

Comment: That brings back an `Request header field Content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` in the console.log.

Comment: Sorry, still coming back with the `client_id not specified` error.

Comment: Yeah, still getting that same error. Thanks anyway - will mark it up as the answer. Looks like I'll have to reassess which method I use and look more into how to use node.js

Answer (score 0):

Access Token Generation Url =>https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/oauth2/token

Headers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP1HG.png)

For the Case of body in Post man select 'x-www-form-urlencoded'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEzRw.png)

After that you will get the respective expected result with token

```
{"access_token":"S-z3mxAqsZBeihx8NgFmNGsZAUGfzKZWCYVV2TiQO422u9XDLTCTZAkpoecyxx_LAc71I_tPkeeOlo2Pzkapv01bBOA03SzMRjRMOm-h3ljTl-pb3XdffoyYjCflE4F8LD377DbpjDWkupkdTaxJpg..","expires_in":7200}
```